# Red light blinking thermaltake versa n23

Tags: ssd, case

I haven't plugged my PC in a while and today I noticed a **red light**.(in front of the case **next to the power button**) I am not sure if it was on before. I found the manual for the case. Can someone tell me should I take it to a specialist or it's nothing to worry about?
Here is the manual:
http://nordic.thermaltake.com/products-model_support.aspx?id=C_00002783

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It's showing disk activity ...